# How can a deleted account ever accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict) struck me as curious because there are complaints that the OP never accepted an answer; however, afaict that asker's account doesn't exist anymore. Is there any way to get the highest-ranking answer "accepted" because of this unusual circumstance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the complaint is from before that account was deleted. The answer is simply that deleted accounts cannot accept answers. The "accepted" check mark belongs to the asker, so this question is not going to have an accepted answer, ever.

… unless someone ended up being merged into that deleted account, although I'm not sure if that is ever done (or even possible, for that matter).

Comment: It's technically possible.

Comment: @Chichiray It's actually not; mods can't merge an account that's already been deleted

Comment: @Michael: But the account is still in the DB and has all posts referenced. So, it's technically possible. Perhaps only the votes are lost, I'm not sure, a SEDE query should prove that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accept if you don't exist, so these questions can't be accepted anymore.

Besides, not everybody accepts answers on each question. Accepting is voluntary. It is good practice to do so.